# How do I sync my iPhone 8’s contacts to my 2014 Honda Accord?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, contacts

I have an iPhone 8 connected to my 2014 Accord via [HandsFreeLink](http://handsfreelink.com/Honda/en-US/US/CustomerResourcesAndHelp/Index) (this is different than CarPlay). However, it won’t sync my phone book to my vehicle. I get the error “Unable to import phonebook”. How can I import my contacts to my vehicle? I’m using iOS 11.4.

Comment: What do you mean you sync via "hands free link"?  Are you talking about Car Play?  How are you connecting to the car?  How are you trying to sync contacts?  Can any other device sync contacts to this car?  Honda's have had problems syncing contacts since iOS 11.  What steps have you already tried to fix this (delete pairing, repair, etc)?  It's really difficult to make recommendations because we don't know what you've or how you're doing it.

Comment: I believe it’s different than Car Play http://handsfreelink.com/Honda/en-US/US/CustomerResourcesAndHelp/Index

Comment: It’s connecting via Bluetooth..

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and any other relevant info there instead of the comments?  The comments are not indexed for searches.

Comment: I’ve just really tried to make sure the contacts sync button was on in my Accord (which it is) and Bluetooth is on (on my phone), which that is as well.

Comment: I suspect you may have more luck asking on a forum dealing with cars rather than here.